# Write python with joblib in parallel in the list

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I use `joblib` to work in parallel, I want to write the results in parallel in a list.

So as to avoid problems, I create an `ldata = []` list beforehand, so that it can be easily accessed.

During parallelization, the data are available in the list, but no longer when they are put together.

How can data be saved in parallel?

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import multiprocessing

data = []

def worker(i):    
    ldata = []
    ...                     # create list ldata    
    data[i].append(ldata)

for i in range(0, 1000):
    data.append([])

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(worker)(i) for i in range(0, 1000))

resultlist = []

for i in range(0, 1000):
    resultlist.extend(data[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at `Parallel` as a parallel `map` operation that does not allow for side effects. The execution model of `Parallel` is that it by default starts new worker copies of the master processes, serialises the input data, sends it over to the workers, have them iterate over it, then collects the return values. Any change a worker performs on `data` stays in its own memory space and is thus invisible to the master process. You have two options here:

First, you can have your workers return `ldata` instead of updating `data[i]`. In that case, `data` will have to be assigned the result returned by `Parallel(...)(...)`:

```
def worker(i):
   ...
   return ldata

data = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(worker)(i) for i in range(0, 1000))
```

Second option is to force a shared memory semantics that uses threads instead of processes. When works execute in threads, their memory space is that of the master process, which is where `data` lies originally. To enforce this semantics, add `require='sharedmem'` keyword argument in the call to `Parallel`:

```
Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores, require='sharedmem')(delayed(worker)(i) for i in range(0, 1000))
```

The different modes and semantics are explained in the `joblib` documentation [here](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html).

Keep in mind that your `worker()` function is written in pure Python and is therefore interpreted. This means that worker threads can't run fully concurrently even if there is just one thread per CPU due to the dreaded Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). This is also explained in the documentation. Therefore, you'd better stick with the first solution in general, despite the marshalling and interprocess communication overheads.

Comment: yes I have already tried the second option, but the speed advantage is no longer valid. I will continue to investigate the first method. If my worker returns a list, I get many different lists, how are they in my master process? [[list 1], [list2], [list3], [...] ...] or [list1, list2, list3, ...]

Comment: If `list1`, `list2`, etc., are lists themselves and not the actual content of each list, then what you get is `[list1, list2, ...]`. Example: `[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], ...]` provided that input 0 maps to `[1,2,3]`, input 1 maps to `[2,3,4]`, etc.